# How can I get a raycast to hit navmesh only?

Tags: unity, navmesh

In Unity, I'm trying to get the raycast to hit the navmesh only, but I cannot find an option to place navmesh on a specific layer.

Is there a way to raycast to the navmesh itself?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish? The navmesh is not a physics object visible to raycasts, but we might be able to implement the feature you have in mind in a different way.

Comment: That is an answer enough. Thank you.

Comment: [You can fire a "navigation ray" along the navmesh to see if it hits a boundary](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMesh.Raycast.html), or [find the closest point on the navmesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMesh.SamplePosition.html), or [the nearest edge from a point on the navmesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMesh.FindClosestEdge.html) - are any of those what you're looking for? For the benefit of future users, I'd like to get this question to a place where we can post a more useful answer than "no".

Comment: `NavMesh.Raycast()` sounds like what you want. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Yeah, I looked into navmesh Raycast. The objective is to sample the navmesh without a ray terminating against things like walls. The Nav ray mentioned above would still suffer from the limitations expressed in the post, unless I am misunderstanding it's function.

Comment: Do the other features that DMGregory suggested solve your issue?